# Portfolio construction with volume based bars

Tags: volatility, portfolio-management, risk, volume

In the book Efficiently Inefficient, Lasse Pedersen interviews Myron Scholes:

**LHP**: Why do spreads tend to widen during some periods of stress?

**MS**: Well, capital becomes more scarce, both physical capital and human capital, in the sense that there isn't enough time for intermediaries to understand what is happening in chaotic times. *Finance is in volatility time, not calendar time.*

---

This italicized observation is interesting to me because a lot of basic trading strategies use fixed parameters, for example his 12-month time series momentum in Chapter 12. If finance is in volatility time, 12 months in 2009 is not the same as 12 months in 2017.

A potential answer to this (assuming volume and volatility are highly correlated) is to use volume based bars instead of time based bars, for example: https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/blog/2012/10/23/constant-volume-bars-vs-time-bars/

For a systematic portfolio strategy though, this is challenging because the nth bars for different assets aren't comparable. For example, if you calculate volume based bars for SPY,QQQ,DIA, and then calculate a return series from these bars, I don't see a way to calculate a meaningful correlation matrix.

Is there a way of dealing with volatility time in a systematic context?

Comment: by " is challenging because the nth bars for different assets aren't comparable", do u mean that they aren't comparable because volume bars for asset 1 are different length (has different number of observations) than volume bars for asset 2? Incomparable return series lengths is all I could think is being asked here since you then talk about the correlation matrix, which would require them to be of same length?